# How to stop my menu dropdown appearing when the dropdown itself is hovered over rather than just the parent button?

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu dropdown from the code below but when I hover over the dropdown button it works as expected. However, when I then hover over the dropdown itself (not the button) the menu keeps appearing. How can I make it so the menu dropdown would only appear when the button is hovered over?

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: none;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1; 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D I've edited and reduced my code to as far as I think I can take it.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue, but if the `.dropdown-content` is supposed to disappear when you're no longer hovering over the `.dropbtn` then how would you ever click on one of the links within the `.dropdown-content`?  Surely you need it to remain visible?

Comment: Or is the issue that you're using `visibility` instead of `display`... meaning if you bring the mouse *up* then it appears before you get to the dropdown?

Comment: Toggling `display` instead of `visibility` fixes the issue, but then breaks the fade transition.

Comment: @David - fair comment, didn't think of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use `visibility : collapse;` instead of `visibility : none;`

also use this css for visibility:

```css
.dropbtn:hover + .dropdown-content ,
.dropdown-content:hover {
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position   : absolute;
  z-index    : 1;
  opacity    : 0;
  visibility : collapse;
  transition : all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.dropbtn:hover  + .dropdown-content ,
.dropdown-content:hover {
  opacity    : 1; 
  visibility : visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also added some improvements to your original post...
see also [css nesting features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting)

```css
    
body {
  background : white;
  }
p {
  max-width  : 36em; 
  }
.dropdownBox {
  width      : fit-content; /* todo initial width === button width */

  &:hover button {          /* see fit-content usage */
    background : #3e8e41;  
    }
  & button {
    position   : relative;
    display    : inline-block;
    cursor     : pointer;
    color      : white;
    background : #04AA6D;
    padding    : 16px;
    font-size  : 16px;
    border     : none;
    }
  & nav {
    position   : absolute;
    background : #f1f1f1;
    min-width  : 160px;
    box-shadow : 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index    : 1;
    opacity    : 0;
    visibility : collapse;
    transition : all .25s ease-in-out;
    }    
  & nav a {
    color    : black;
    padding  : 12px 16px;
    display  : block;
    }
  & nav a:hover {
    background : #ddd;
    }
  }
.dropdownBox button:hover + nav ,
.dropdownBox nav:hover {
  opacity    : 1; 
  visibility : visible;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the drop down menu.</p>

<div class="dropdownBox">  <!-- use one class for your structure -->
  <button>Dropdown</button>  
  <nav>
    <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#3">Link 3</a>
  </nav> 
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor,
  dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, 
  varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, 
  non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper.  
</p>
```

Comment: @EJ740 I don't know if my answer is indifferent to you or not, but I spent some time (see second snippet) hoping that you would validate it.

Answer (score 1):

`none` [isn't a valid option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) for the `visibility` style.  (Or at least a non-standard option?)  The browser is essentially doing its best to fix the problem, and the result (at least for me) is that the element is there on the page (and thus hoverable) but not shown.

Use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `visibility: none;`

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1; 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```